# Spring 4.3: Is it problematic to load a DataSource in a DAO instead of in a @Bean configuration

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, datasource, jndi

Is it ok to access a datasource in a Spring DAO in the following way (rather than configuring a bean and autowiring it):

```
@Repository
public class MyDAOImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements MyDAO {


    @PostConstruct
    private void initialize() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        lookup.setResourceRef(true);
        DataSource dataSource = lookup.getDataSource("jdbc/TWO");
        super.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    public MyStuff getMyStuff(Long id) {
        // getJdbcTemplate().query() etc
    }

}
```

This works but is it ok or will this cause problems? Maybe create a connection leak or something else?

Thanks

(Edited for clarity)

Comment: "... but it's not working" - what does that mean? Do you get an error message? What is the exact error message?

Comment: Yes the error is "No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate" and it mentions the @Qualifier and its "dataSourceTwo" value

Comment: Why are you using JNDI to define the DataSource as a bean, and then in your code use JNDI to lookup the data source instead of injecting the bean? Also, please provide the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel the Bean is removed from the code and just here as an example of what wasn't working, I think I will take it out of the question as it is confusing. My question really is about the using the lookup in the DAO

Comment: Your edit only confuses matters further I think. If you haven't defined data sources as beans, then that is the actual cause of the error: you haven't defined any data sources as beans, but your code or configuration is expecting a data source to be injected.

Comment: The code is now working with the lookup in the PostConstruct method, I'm just wondering if this is an OK way to do it. (I'm not using a bean configuration or trying to autowire a datasource in this case)